# ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqt4

I run myscript and get this error:

```
from qgis.core import * # @UnusedWildImport
from qgis.gui import * # @UnusedWildImport
from PyQt4.QtCore import * # @UnusedWildImport
from PyQt4.QtGui import * # @UnusedWildImport
# Import the code for the dialog
from delineationdialog import DelineationDialog
***(code continues)***
```

Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Program Files/QGIS 2.18/apps/qgis/python/plugins/HidroTurk/HT_HJK/delineation.py", line 28, in <module>
    from delineationdialog import DelineationDialog
  File "C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis\python\plugins\HidroTurk\HT_HJK\delineationdialog.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ..UIs.ui_delineation import Ui_QgsOptionsBase
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

here is the DelineationDialog:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from ..UIs.ui_delineation import Ui_QgsOptionsBase


class DelineationDialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_QgsOptionsBase):
    """Set up dialog from designer."""
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor."""
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        # After setupUI you can access any designer object by doing
        # self.<objectname>, and you can use autoconnect slots - see
        # http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html
        # #widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect
        self.setupUi(self)
```

Comment: How do you launch your script?

Comment: in pycharm interpereter is QGIS 2.18/bin/python.exe